# How to merge two or more arrays in angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two arrays that are comming from a url. I am trying to join the two arrays as a single array in angular

```js
"admin":[
{
"Name":"John",
"Age":34
},
{
"Name:"Joe",
"Age":56
}
],
"users":[
{
"Name":"John",
"Age":34
},
{
"Name:"Joe",
"Age":56
}
]
```

I tried to join the two arrays by

```js
public newArr=[];
join(){
this.newArr=this.newArray.concat(this.admin,this.users)
console.log(this.this.newArr.length);
//the result shown in the console is 0
}
```

I tried another method

```js
join(){
this.newArr.push(...this.users,...this.admins)
console.log(this.newArr.length)
//the results is still 0
}
```

Please how do I go about that

Comment: you combine them correctly in both examples. it seems at the moment of combining you don't have those arrays filled yet.could you provide code where you get the data?

Comment: getdata(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>('assets/users.json')
  }

Comment: and a piece of code where you call `getdata()` and then combine the arrays

Comment: I then subscribe to it  this.getdata().subscribe(data=> this.users = data);

Comment: so that is the problem. please, provide this code in the question. you will get an answer, how to fix it properly

Answer (score 3):

simply use **The destructuring assignment** .
you can get more info in this page [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
public newArr=[...this.admin,...this.users];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public newArr=[];
join(){
  this.newArr=this.admin.concat(this.users)
  console.log(this.newArr.length);
}
```